# JSON to Avro conversion using Java

Tags: java, json, avro

I want to convert JSON data into Avro file. So how can I do it through Java API/code?

My sample JSON file is:

```
[
  {
    "ProductID": "101.0",
    "Id": "1.0",
    "OrderID": "1111.0",
    "Name": "John"
  },
  {
    "ProductID": "102.0",
    "Id": "2.0",
    "OrderID": "2222.0",
    "Name": "Taylor"
  }
]
```

So 1st thing, how can I create Avro schema file from JSON file?

Secondly, after creating Avro schema, how to convert it into Avro file?

Answer (score 2):

Check if the below code is useful for you.

```
public <T> T jsonDecodeToAvro(String inputString, Class<T> className,
Schema schema) {

     T returnObject = null;

     try {

         JsonDecoder jsonDecoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema,
inputString);

         SpecificDatumReader<T> reader = new
SpecificDatumReader<T>(className);

         returnObject = reader.read(null, jsonDecoder);

     } catch (IOException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();

     }



     return returnObject;
}
```

Comment: Hi, If i keep type of avro schema as `String`, then i'm getting an error at jsonDecoder(schema, inputstring). because json Decoder expects the type of schema to be `Schema`. So how can solve it?

Comment: Any suggestions or updates?

Comment: I'm not sure. Will update you if I find any.

Comment: new Schema.Parser().parse(jsonString) will convert your schema stored as a Json string into a Schema object.